# Why do I get "Invalid Form Body" when trying to embed a local image in a message?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Right now I'm working on making a bot that will post a random image from a local folder on my VSC. However, posting an [embed message](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview) with the image results in an error:

> DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
> embeds[0].image.url: Could not interpret "{'attachment': ['1.jpg', '2mkjR-3__400x400.jpg', '8921036_sa.jpg', '91Vk1mS1x3L.png'], 'name': None}" as string.

This can be reproduced with the sample code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Intents } = Discord;
const fs = require('fs');

const config = require('config');
const authToken = config.get('authToken');

const myIntents = new Intents([
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
]);
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: myIntents });

client.on("ready", (client) => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}.`);
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if ('.pic' === message.content) {
        let files = fs.readdirSync('./assets/images/');
        let chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];
        const image = new Discord.MessageAttachment(files);
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle('yeet')
              .setImage(image)
              .setFooter('By K4STOR','');
        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
    }
});

client.login(authToken);
```

In addition to the above script, you'll need to:

- create an 'assets/images' directory and
- add at least one image;
- create a configuration file (e.g. 'config/local.json') and
- add an appropriate 'authToken' entry

How can the above code be fixed to send the image?

Comment: Please add the error you get when trying or what is the expected behavior vs what you get.

Comment: You're using `readFilesSync` to find the files in a directory. You need to use `readdirSync` [How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a directory in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j)

Comment: @Samathingamajig I did that and now Im getting an error stating "embed.image.url: Could not interpret "{'attachment': ['1.jpg', '2mkjR-3__400x400.jpg', '8921036_sa.jpg', '91Vk1mS1x3L.png'], 'name': None}" as string."

Comment: @Sky readdirSync returns an array of all the files in the folder. You can not use an array as source for your image.

Comment: @Sky: information relevant to the question should be edited into the question, rather than left in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Sky: Note that, in general, you shouldn't change a question for a new issue but should post a new question instead. However, as your original question would have been closed, rewriting it is acceptable. This is because SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. All information (such as error messages) should be added to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), not left as [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments.

Comment: ... Also, your most recent code did not produce the error you showed since you passed embed directly to `message.channel.send()`, which resulted in an error about the message being empty (as per the API, the `send()` argument should either be a string, a `MessageOptions` or a `MessagePayload`). It also referred to various undefined symbols. While most (e.g. `Discord`, `fs`) were standard parts of node.js and discord.js, `command` was not, and implementing it to make the code work is not a trivial task. [Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be complete and representative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How do I use a local image on a discord.js rich embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51199950/90527)", "[Discord.js random image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49677884/90527)", "[Getting an array from folder and sending a random file with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50851030/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

client.on("ready", () => {
    
    console.log("Why did I make this...")

    command(client, 'pic', (message) => {
        //choose one file from folder "./images" randomly
        var files = fs.readdirSync("./images/")
        let chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]
 
        //create embed and use image from messageAttachments
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('yeet')
            .setImage(`attachment://${chosenFile}`)
            .setFooter('By K4STOR','')

        //discord.js V13 variant of sending embeds
        //necessary to set files, otherwise #setImage with localfile does not work
        message.channel.send({
          embeds: [embed], 
          files: [`./images/${chosenFile}`]
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

### Main Issue

[`MessageEmbed.setImage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setImage) takes a URL, not a `MessageAttachment`. For attachments, you must pass them via the `files` [option](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/BaseMessageOptions) [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send). Note the guide on [attaching images to an embed message](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#attaching-images) shows this.

Additionally, the path to the image directory must be combined with the chosen file name when the attachment object is created.

### Minor issue

Note that all images appear in the error message. This is due to a minor issue: the attachment is set to `files`, rather than `chosenFile`. Note this sort of issue is considered on SO.

### Changes

Just these changes would look like:

```
const path = require('path');
...
const imgDir = './assets/images/';
...
        const image = new Discord.MessageAttachment(
            path.join(imgDir, chosenFile),
            chosenFile,
            {url: 'attachment://' + chosenFile});
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setImage(image.url)
              ...
        
        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], files: [image]});
```

### Full Sample

The sample with the above changes applied would be:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Intents } = Discord;
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const config = require('config');
const authToken = config.get('authToken');

const myIntents = new Intents([
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
]);
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: myIntents });

client.on("ready", (client) => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}.`);
});

const imgDir = './assets/images/';
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if ('.pic' === message.content) {
        let files = fs.readdirSync(imgDir);
        let chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];
        const image = new Discord.MessageAttachment(
            path.join(imgDir, chosenFile),
            chosenFile,
            {url: 'attachment://' + chosenFile});
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle('yeet')
              .setImage(image.url)
              .setFooter('By K4STOR','');
        console.log(`Sending ${chosenFile}.`);
        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], files: [image]});
    }
});

client.login(authToken);
```